# Autocomplete not filling form value in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have several INPUT tags in a register form.
One of the INPUTs is named email

```
<input type=text name=email id=email>
```

When I fill this form in Chrome, I click to the input field for email, type "t" and then chrome offers dropdown menu with suggested values (emails entered earlier). Now, I hover my mouse over the first item (email) and the value appears immediately in the form input, without clicking anywhere. So, I think, now the value is in the input field, ok? But surprisingly, it's not!

[image]

If I select the suggeted autocomplete value by clicking, it is there. But if I just hover mouse over the row (which immediately adds the value to the displayed input), it doesn't change the internal value. So querying the value as

```
console.log( $('#email').val() )
```

prints 't' only. As well as

```
console.log( document.getElementById('email').value )
```

While the value on screen shows entire email. Is this a chrome bug? Why this happens? Is there any way to get the real value?

Comment: try adding [autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) attribute to your email field.

Comment: Tried to add as autocomplete=on, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like enclosing the  field by a  tags fixes the issue. So it appears to be a bug in Chrome which only affects  fields which are not a part of any

I've reported the bug to google.
But I suspect that nobody will care about it for ages now.